# Set file as parameter of **setText()** in **javafx**

Tags: file, directory, javafx-8

Suppose I have a file name `data.txt` in directory `D:\coding\Project 300\Project 300\information`

How can I show that `data.txt` file's content in a `textArea` of `javafx`?

If this directory contains more than one file, how can I choose that specific file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do some work setting the file chooser path, title, and initial dir.  [`FileChooser` link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextReader extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea ta = new TextArea();
        Button btn = new Button("Open");
        btn.setOnAction((e) -> {
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            File file = fc.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            if (file!=null) 
                try {
                    ta.setText(new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())));
                } catch (IOException ex) {}
        });
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(btn,ta)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```